# How to GET data using RestTemplate exchange?

Tags: java, spring-boot, get, resttemplate

I'm currently sending a `GET request` which is returning a `null` body in the response.

```
@Service
public class CarService {
private RestTemplate restTemplate;
private final String url = "url";
private final String accessToken = "x";

@Autowired
public CarService () throws URISyntaxException {
    restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
}

public void fetchCars() throws URISyntaxException {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setBearerAuth(accessToken);
    headers.setAccept(List.of(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    ResponseEntity<CarList> carList = restTemplate.exchange
            (RequestEntity.get(new URI(url)).headers(headers).build(), CarList.class);
}

}
```

The CarList.class looks like this:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class CarList{
    private List<Car> carList;

    public CarList(List<Car> carList) {
        this.carList= carList;
    }

    public CarList() {
    }

    public List<Car> getCarList() {
        return carList;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CarList{" +
                "carList=" + carList +
                '}';
    }
}
```

The response in Postman looks like this:

```
{
    "cars": [
        {
            "carUid": "aaaa-ccc-dd-cc-ee",
            "model": "hyundai",
            "price": 20000,
            "soldAt": "2021-09-24T22:10:15.307Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

Am I missing something?
It's the first time I try to consume from a client, so take in consideration the most basic things that I might be missing.

I've already tested the GET request in Postman with the given accessToken and it's working fine.

Comment: I hope you get some answers but frankly I think this is a problem you can easily debug - any IDE would get the Spring source for you and you can see where the response processing fails.

Comment: I'm getting a 200 response code but the body is null. I'm following the suggestion provided by the other user to solve it. Hopefully it will be fixed soon. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You carList object is private, try providing a setter method for this object and if the contract is fine, the deserialization will work fine.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class CarList{
    private List<Car> carList;

    public CarList(List<Car> carList) {
        this.carList= carList;
    }

    public CarList() {
    }

    public List<Car> getCarList() {
        return carList;
    }

    public setCarList(List<Car> carList) {
        this.carList= carList;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CarList{" +
                "carList=" + carList +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that but still doesn't work. It should be something in the contract. I've edited my question with the expected json response. Thanks!

Comment: It was a problem in the contract, thanks for highlighting that.